# Why do Period will be ignored at the beginning of a sentence in SendEmail on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I want to use command line to send an email on Linux so I choose sendEmail (a lightweight, command line SMTP email client). However, I find Period (.) at the beginning of a sentence will be ignored and it really confused me.

-m MESSAGE                message body

My command:

```
sendEmail -f sender@example.com -t receiver@example.com -u "Test mail" -s smtp.example.com -xu sender@example.com -xp sender_password -m ".Hello\n..Hello\nHello.world" -o tls=no
```

What I want to display is:

```
.Hello
..Hello
Hello.world
```

But the result is:

```
Hello
.Hello
Hello.world
```

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a **bug** in the `sendEmail` client. In SMTP a line containing nothing else but a single period `.` is used to indicate the end of the message (DATA segment in SMTP). To avoid unintended transmission termination if a message contains a line with a single period, on all lines starting with a period an extra period has to be added before the message goes onto the wire; and removed upon receive. It's the task of a proper SMTP client to take care of this. It's clearly a faulty behavior of the client.
To get around the bug, add an extra period.

For details see [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321), sections 4.1.1.4 and 4.5.4.